# How to select a row with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following script that is getting its variable via URL then is processed in mysql and then the location of that file will be loaded in an html5 player but i cant figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```
<?php  
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("media") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title='.$_GET['pattern']'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$location = $result[location];
}
 ?> 

<object classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616"
            width="80%" height="90%" 
        codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab">
        <param name="src" value="sam.mkv"/>

        <embed
        type="video/divx"
        src="<?php '.$info "?>"`enter code here`
        width="80%" height="400px"
        pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Please fix the title of your question first.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: You need to escape your user input before inserting.

Comment: you have the source as `$info` but `$info` is nowhere else in your code.. i'm assuming that should be `$location`. and $result should be `mysql_fetch_array($query)` .. look up some basic tutorials on this stuff instead of copy pasting from examples

Comment: Turn error reporting on and you will see you have unmatched quotes and concatenation issues.. alternatively use a better editor with syntax highlighting and you'll be able to see it easily.

Comment: src="<?php '.$info "?>"`enter code here` - This part looks problematic.

Comment: `mysql_` - functions are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: sql injection attacks arnt important as it is a local media streaming server. it has no connection to the outside world but i understand, i'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a whole lot of things wrong.

1. You **didn't escape the GET value** before using it in a query
2. You didn't read the code before you posted it, and **simply copied it** from somewhere
3. Your code is full of **syntax errors** and nonsense
4. ***You are using deprecated `mysql_*` functions***

---

Here is the code, with the most obvious errors fixed:

```
<?php  

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("media") or die(mysql_error()); 

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pattern']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title='$title' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$location = $row['location'];

?> 

<object 
    classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616"
    width="80%" height="90%" 
    codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab">

    <param name="src" value="sam.mkv"/>

    <embed
    type="video/divx"
    src="<?php echo $location; ?>"
    width="80%" height="400px"
    pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much MightPork it worked!

Comment: If it worked, then why not accept the answer?

Comment: No, you didn't. If you did, there would've been the green tick mark under the votes count.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$location = $result[location];
```